# Unable to move the file because it is being used in another process

Tags: vb.net, process, adobe

In my project I launch a batch file (not mine) that opens a pdf file, I wait 7000 milliseconds, then I close the Adobe processes and repeat the sequence again, at the end of everything I move the file to a new folder, but every now and then the program goes in exception
the function I use is this (vb.net):

```
Function Close(name as  String)
{
 dim processList as Process() = Process.GetProcessByName(name)
If processList.Count < 0 then 
 processList = Process.GetProcessByName(“AcroRd32”)
End If

For i as Integer = 0 to processList.Count - 1
 processList(i).CloseMainWindow()
Next
}
```

I state that this exception when testing my program had never happened, in the client's desk it happened

Comment: My question is, opening a pdf for a set time period seems quite an odd requirement.  Does this actually need to happen?  Why just move the file?  Even if the file is still needing viewing, open it after moving maybe where you won't have the same potential issues around open file handles

Comment: The customer's specification was to launch the bat file (I think he opens the pdf and prints it with a vbs script, they never wanted to provide it to me for testing) 2 times and then move it renaming the original file